# Pandas DF issue:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Df 1]

[image: Df 2]

How do i get table 1(df 1) in the form of table 2 (df 2) in pandas?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your question properly.

Comment: please post data and don't post screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to have 2 dataframes, one with only `tesco1` and the other with only `tesco2`.

Then I would use a `merge` with

```
df.merge(df2,how='left',left_on=['client'],right_on=['client"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `. explode` like this

```
df2 =df1.explode(title)
```